# Filter href out of selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have these piece of code:

```
record = game.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)')
```

Depending on the page I run that on, I get either a link between that specific `td` tag or just text.  For example I don't want any links like below:

```
<td><a href="https://www.uselesslink.com">Useless link text</a></td>
```

But I do need:

```
<td>Here is some juicy text</td>
```

I need to be able to filter the link so that if a link is found, I can just print "None".  So something like this:

```
if record has link:
    print('Nothing to show')
else:
    print('text found')
```

There must be an easy way to test for `href` or an `a` tag but I can't seem to nail it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if `a` is found this way:

```
if record.a is not None:  # link found
```

`record.a` is a shortcut to `record.find("a")`, `.find()` method returns `None` if an element is not found.

Comment: Ahh, yes I feel silly now.  Man, BS4 has so many options for doing things its hard to keep it all straight!

Comment: @Biggen right, that flexibility BS4 offers sometimes results into "too much ways to do one thing" problem :) But, seriously, it has one of the best APIs out there.